# ¿Por qué no da el resultado correcto y me repite numeros?

Tags: java, hilos

Este es el ejercicio: Dado un entero n divisible por 5, calcula la suma de todos los enteros desde 1 hasta n, ambos incluidos. Divide el trabajo en, al menos, 5 hilos.
El problema es que si le pongo 10 de número pues debería de salir losen cada iteración del bucle 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 sin embargo me sale sum 1
sum 3
sum 7
sum 1
sum 3
sum 5
sum 5
sum 7
sum 9
sum 9

Este es mi código:

```
public class Hilo1 extends Thread {

    private int a;
    private int b;


    public Hilo1(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("a "+a);
         System.out.println("b "+b);
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public Hilo1() {


    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        double sum = 0;
        Numero.setSuma(sum);
        for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        sum += a;
         System.out.println("sum "+sum);
        }
    }
}


public class Numero {

    private static int numero;
    private static double suma;

    public static int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public static void setNumero(int numero) {
        Numero.numero = numero;
    }

    public static double getSuma() {
        return suma;
    }

    public static void setSuma(double suma) {
        Numero.suma += suma;
    }

    public static List partes(int numero) {
        List<Integer> limites = new ArrayList<>();
        if (numero % 5 == 0) {
            limites.add(1);
            int c = numero / 5;
            limites.add(c);
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                int a;
                if (c == 1) {
                    a = i;
                } else {
                    a = c * i + 1;
                }
                limites.add(a);
                int b = c * (i + 1);

                limites.add(b);
            }
        }
        return limites;
    }

}


     public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Introduce el numero divisible por 5: ");
            Numero.setNumero(Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine()));
            List partes = Numero.partes(Numero.getNumero());
            Hilo1 sum1 = new Hilo1((int) partes.get(0), (int) partes.get(1));
            Hilo1 sum2 = new Hilo1((int) partes.get(2), (int) partes.get(3));
            Hilo1 sum3 = new Hilo1((int) partes.get(4), (int) partes.get(5));
            Hilo1 sum4 = new Hilo1((int) partes.get(6), (int) partes.get(7));
            Hilo1 sum5 = new Hilo1((int) partes.get(8), (int) partes.get(9));
            sum1.start();
            sum2.start();
            sum3.start();
            sum4.start();
            sum5.start();

        }
```

Si el print de sum le quitamos el + de manera que nos de solo los números que salen en el bucle me da los que he puesto arriba sum 1 sum 3 en vez de lo que debería dar

Comment: no revise todo, pero dentro del metodo run, esto esta mal: sum += a;.. deberia ser sum += i, si no siempre estas sumando el valor inicial...

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es que la correr el bucle se impriman los numero del 1 al 10 (no se si entendí mal), únicamente necesitas reemplazar:

```
for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
 sum += a;
 System.out.println("sum "+sum);
}
```

por:

```
for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

para mostrar las sumatorias respectivas desde 1 a 5 (n = 5):

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        sum += i;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

resultado : 1 3 6 10 15